# Storing the values of an iteration to a tensor - Python, Numpy, pytorch

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i was trying to save values for N for every epoch, problem is each time it overwrites,

np.savetxt("normalfeature.txt", np.array([N]), fmt="%s")

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('normalfeature.txt','ab') as file:
    np.savetext(file, np.array([N]), delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: first of all thank you so much for your advice. now it save 2 and than overwrite again. unlike last time it stored only 1st epochs values only.

np.savetxt("normalfeature.txt", np.array([N]), fmt="%s")

with open('normalfeature.txt','ab') as file:
    np.savetxt(file, np.array([N]), delimiter=",", fmt="%s")